# Alternatives to Google Groups with more features?

Tags: webapp-rec, google-groups

The development efforts on Google Groups is glacial. They still aren't integrated with Google Calendar or Picasa. Subgroups are still only available for Google's own groups. What alternatives are there to Google Groups for the purpose of hosting a discussion group? I would like something with more features than what Google Groups offers.

Comment: what about [buddypress](http://buddypress.org/)? drawback is that you have to host it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [GroupSpaces](http://groupspaces.com) - I was looking for a Google Groups replacement for managing a mailing list, and it seems to fit the bill really nicely.

Answer (score 2):

[Yahoo! Groups](http://groups.yahoo.com) offers much of what Google Groups does. In their favor I like that the calendar is integrated better and you can have (nested!) folders.

I moved away from Yahoo! Groups because I found the ads intrusive. (I do miss good file management, though.)

Comment: Yahoo groups does have some nice features like polls

Answer (score 0):

You can try [The Fridge](http://www.frid.ge/) which is creating for you some sort of group-Facebook. Everyone who gets invited sees all information in this social network. It has an activity stream on the homepage, you can comment, leave wall post, or upload photos. There are no profile fields to fill out (unlike Facebook) and unfortunately no calendar.

Comment: Interesting, but not quite what I am looking fot

Comment: "We are pleased to announce that Fridge has been acquired by Google!" they are closed until integrated into Google+